# What is external_id in Podio API?

Tags: podio

What is it's purpose and what are good practices about it? Should it be a random number? A string with meaning?

It doesn't seem like it's set automatically when an item is created *in* Podio.

I want a unique id to differentiate different items in a Podio app, is external_id the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate between items with their `item_id` which will always be unique.